# How to show the Edition DisplayName in multiple languages

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

Is the Edition DisplayName localizable? If not, what's the best practice in the code to make it localizable?

I want to be able to change the Edition DisplayName without re-deploying the application in multiple languages.

I am using the ASP.Net Core / Angular version - ASP.Net Zero.

Comment: What is "Edition Name"?!

Comment: It is a feature in asp.net zero (asp.net boiler plate) https://aspnetboilerplate.com/

Comment: Edition DisplayName is static. In real world apps, edition names are usually static and doesn't change according to the language of users. Forexample,cars have editions but they have the same name in all countries (Renault > Megane: JOY / ICON / PRIVILAGE / TOUCH ...) May be you have to rethink about your business model.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu Well, the Edition name is "Free", "Business", "Team". Not totally a version or a brand name. It can be translated like office365 in Turkish https://products.office.com/tr-tr/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?tab=1 (EV, Bireysel, Öğrenci)

Answer (score 1):

You can map your `ILocalizableString` to a `string`, Automapper will transalte it.
You can create your Localizable string like this:

```
new LocalizableString(edition.Name, "localizationFileName");
```

If you want to understand better what automapper does you can find it in AbpAutoMapperModule.cs, method CreateCoreMappings.

**EDIT**: Maybe you can configure your specific mapping like:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(CreateMappings);
}
private void CreateCoreMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
{
     var localizationContext = IocManager.Resolve<ILocalizationContext>();
     configuration.CreateMap<Edition, EditionDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayName, options => options.MapFrom(src => localizationContext.LocalizationManager.GetString("localizationFileName", src.DisplayName)))
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I got you correctly. I made like this

`public class EditionListDto : EntityDto, IHasCreationTime
 {
        public LocalizableString DisplayName { get; set; }
   }`

but it throwed an "AutoMapperAutoMappingException"

Comment: Your dto should have the string property, while your entity should have a LocalizableString,

Comment: I don't have access to the entity since it is in a Nuget library. Also, won't this affect the EF upgrade since I am changing the data type of an entity ?